# How to calculate the length of the portion of curve from given conditions.

Tags: functions, plane-curves, line-integrals, arc-length

Let $l$ be the length of the portion of the curve $x=x(y)$ between the lines $y=1$ and $y=2$ where $x(y)$ staisfy $\sqrt \frac {1+y^2+y^4}{y} \ , x(1)=0$. Then find $l$ .

**The main thing I didn't get in this question is 
 $x(y)$  satisfy $\sqrt \frac {1+y^2+y^4}{y}$ what does it imply?**

According to me the function will be of this type
$$x(y)=(y-1)f(y)$$ 
Where $f(y)$ is a function which have to find it to evaluate the arc length.
$$l=\int_{1}^{2} \sqrt { ( \frac {dx}{dy})^2 +1} \ \  dy$$

See here Exact image of question.[image]

**The correct answer is 2.195**

Comment: The question probably has a typo and should rad $x(y)$ satisfies $x(y)=\sqrt{...}$, in which case, you can evaluate $dy/dx$ and use the arc length formula.

Comment: @ZachBoyd but it will complicate if $x(y)=\sqrt{...}$. Can you give hint to solve it

Comment: I am not sure how without looking at it more.

Comment: @ZachBoyd if it satisfies square root expression. Then it will not satisfy$x(1)=0$.

Comment: That’s true. Maybe that expression is the derivative instead, which would explain the need for an initial condition. I think that there is a bad typo in the question that may make it too ambiguous.